# Negative coefficients in regression - market mix modelling

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have a dataset with 36 rows with 5 columns.
The columns are Sales, Distribution, TV-GRP, Spent_Non-TV, Spent_on_Promotion of one brand.

When I run correlation, Distribution is highly correlated with sales (0.95) but other variables are not well correlated (<0.4) with Sales. In regression model, taking Sales as dependent variable, and all other variables are independent variables, we are getting a high positive coefficient for distribution but getting a negative coefficients for other independent variables (TV-GRP, Spent_Non-TV, Spent_on_Promotion).

I tried doing different types of variables transformations but almost getting the similar results.
My assumption is that the marketing strategies(TV-GRP, Spent_Non-TV, Spent_on_Promotion) must have some impact on Sales. Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

When doing multivariable regression, you must be sure the independent variables do not strongly correlate among themselves, or the model will yield bad coefficients and bad predictions.

Have in mind that, in multivariable regression, a coefficient means that the dependent variable grows **y** units when the independent variable grows one unit, *all the other variables being constant*. Now, if they strongly correlate, one variable *will not* vary if the others are constant, it will have vary small variance, which makes the prediction bad.

If the variables correlate, you can a) get rid of some of them or b) have some dimensionality reduction on the data. Also, a good metric for that is [Variance InflationError](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor).